# How to Get Data from checkbox selected row in dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using this [data table](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html).

I need to get both `ProductID` & `ProductStatus` from the selected row where ProductID is embedded in the TR ID of each row.

I'm not displaying the productStatus in the table. But I need to get the status when the row is selected. Where can i add them ?

Please Guide me ....

**CODE**

```
function loadClick() {

  const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('S01/Products');
  var query = databaseRef.orderByKey().startAt("C09M03S03").endAt("C09M03S04").limitToFirst(6);

  query.once("value")
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

        var t = $('#products_table').DataTable();

        var key = childSnapshot.key;

        var MID = childSnapshot.child("productMID").val();
        var SID = childSnapshot.child("productSID").val();
        var ProductID = childSnapshot.child("productID").val();
        var name = childSnapshot.child("productName").val();
        var unit = childSnapshot.child("productUnit").val();
        var productMRP = childSnapshot.child("productMRP").val();
        var price = childSnapshot.child("productSellingPrice").val();
        var buying_price = childSnapshot.child("productBuyingPrice").val();
        var productstatus = childSnapshot.child("productStatus").val();

        var row = "";

        t.row.add(['<td class="cell-60 responsive-hide"></td><td class="cell-300"><a class="avatar" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="img-responsive" src="../../../global/portraits/1.jpg"alt="..."></a></td>', '<td>' + name + '</td>',
        '<td>' + unit + '</td>', '<td tabindex="1">' + productMRP + '</td>', '<td tabindex="2">' + price + '<\/td>',
        '<td tabindex="3">' + buying_price + '<\/td>']).node().id = ProductID;
        t.draw(false);

      });
    });
}

function EditProdStatus(ProductID, ProductStatus) {
  var statusRef = firebase.database().ref('S01/Products').child(ProductID).child("productStatus");
  statusRef.set(!ProductStatus);
  console.log("Product Status changed to " + ProductStatus);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  loadClick();
  var table = $('#products_table').DataTable({
    'columnDefs': [{
      orderable: false,
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      targets: 0
    },
    {
      'targets': 3,
      'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        $(td).attr('tabindex', '1');
      }
    },
    {
      'targets': 4,
      'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        $(td).attr('tabindex', '2');
      }
    },
    {
      'targets': 5,
      'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        $(td).attr('tabindex', '3');
      }
    }
    ],
    select: {
      style: 'os',
      selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']]
  });

});

function productDisable() {

  var oTable = $('#products_table').dataTable();
  $(".select-checkbox:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <table id="products_table" class="table is-indent tablesaw" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                                  <th class="pre-cell"></th>
                                  <th class="cell-300" scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Product Name</th>
                                  <th class="cell-300" scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Product Unit</th>
                                  <th class="cell-300" scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Product MRP</th>
                                  <th class="cell-300" scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Selling Price</th>
                                  <th class="cell-300" scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Buying Price</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                </table>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ArulNadhaN/vjqj7eg5/1/)

Comment: What is the index value for your `product status` column?

Comment: I don't want to show the status in the table. But I need it to send to the function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those `td` which you don't want to display in DataTable, you just need to provide `Visible:false` in your `columnDefs`. They will be hidden but you can retrieve their data if they are in selected rows.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      targets: 0
    }, {
      "targets": [2],
      "visible": false,
      "searchable": false
    }]
})
```

Another thing is you are using `fnGetNodes` which is a legacy function for [datatable v1.9](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) on selection which is not going to work for DataTable 10.1. You can get selected rows as follow:

```
table.rows('.selected').data();
```

This is going to return `selected rows` even if you have selected multiple rows in different pages.

You can find a <kbd>***[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/q67L1a9a/)***</kbd>.

As you can see in demo that for Employees data, their `position` column in not visible in DataTable but its data is available while retrieving data of selected rows.

[Documentation here for Hidden columns](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html)

---

**Update**

I have updated your Fiddle.  <kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/bzxbLy5h/)**</kbd> .

Comment: It worked. But I can't retrieve the Product status & productID ?

Comment: @user3467240 In your html of table you don't have columns for ProductID and ProductStatus.

Comment: And in `t.row.add([....]` you are not adding values for `ProductId` and `ProductStatus`.

Comment: I'm adding ProductID as TR ID for Each row. I have added productStatus as my 2nd columns & set visible to false. 
To make it simple, I need to get the TR ID & the value of 2nd Column of the selected Rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it helps you

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', '.checkbox', function () {
if(this.checked==true)
{
console.log( table.row( this.closest('tr') ).data() );
}
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>check</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ></td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ></td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

Add your `productStatus` column to the HTML :

```
'<td>' + productStatus + '</td>'
```

Let's say that's at column index 8. So add the following to the dataTables `columnDefs` :

```
{
    'targets': 8,
    'visible': false,
}
```

Now, in `productDisable()`, you can get productID & productStatus from each selected row as follows :

```
function productDisable() {
    table.rows(".selected").every(function() {
        var row = this.node();
        var productID = row.id;
        var productStatus = this.data()[8]; 
        console.log(productID, productStatus);
        // do whatever with productID and productStatus
    });
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vjqj7eg5/2/)**

Comment: If you can publish a live demo in jsFiddle or codePen, I'll see if I can debug it.

Comment: jsFiddle - jsfiddle.net/ArulNadhaN/vjqj7eg5/1

Comment: Sorry, that's not working for me at all. I need something at least partially working before I can start debugging the actual issue.

Comment: No matter, I managed to get something working in a local file. See edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

I a using Datatable **1.10** and this Code is Working for me 
"btnSubmit" is the Id of the Button when you click on the button selected checkbox data you will get

```
   // Handle form submission event 
   $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
       //Hold the Object Data what are the checkbox selected
       var tblData = table.api().rows('.selected').data();
       var tmpData;
       //Iterate the Object and extract you one one by one row data With Hidden Id Also
          $.each(tblData, function(i, val) {
            tmpData = tblData[i];
            alert(tmpData);
          }); 
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//You can use this one.
$( $('#example').DataTable().$('.checked').map(function () 
{
    return $(this).closest('tr');
    //want to get attribute
    //var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.Select').attr('id');
}));
```